# How to Check the Validity of Delta-Wye Conversions?

Tags: resistors

I am solving some basic circuits where I am converting the circuits from delta to wye and wye to delta. Now I want to check the validity of my answers. Any hack for that?

Comment: Care expand? if you want to check easily your circuit you can simulate it.

Comment: if you go wye delta, followed by a delta wye, you should get the original parameters back. Checks for 'fat-finger' errors.

Comment: Take one of you circuits that you converted Delta -> Wye and then take that Wye and convert Wye -> Delta, if you get the original circuit you probably did it right, and get more practice at the same time.

Comment: Going back to the original just means that you did something, and then did the inverse.  It doesn't mean that the "something" is right.  It will point out silly mistakes, though.

Comment: Search for a delta wye calculator. There are several that work with simple resistors.